# Maven inserts the dependencies into EAR instead of in the module

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I have this project https://github.com/AndreaCatania/libreria

It's has 3 modules "**deweb**" "**decore**" "**libreriaEar**"

The module **libreriaEar** creates a EAR archive with deweb and decore modules
I'm try to use Hibernate into the module "decore" but maven not import the dependencies into the "decore" module and I receive the NoClassFoundException error.

If I inspects the ear archive, I find all dependencies into it instead of in the module "decore".

**The EAR archive generated**
[image: the EAR archive generated]

**The decore module generated (EJB)**
[image: The decore module generated (EJB)]
what is wrong?

---

**EDIT 1**

Main pom: https://github.com/AndreaCatania/libreria/blob/master/pom.xml

---

**EDIT 2**

I get this error when i deploy the project into the WildFly AS.

```
[0m[31m16:01:10,654 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-9) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."libreriaEar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."decore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."libreriaEar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."decore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "decore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "libreriaEar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
  org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.ac.ejbs.SingBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.libreriaEar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.decore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2575) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1908) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry from [Module "deployment.libreriaEar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.decore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: Post the POMs for starters.

Comment: @chrylis https://github.com/AndreaCatania/libreria/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Post all code, including control files, *in* the question. Otherwise they may be inaccessible or go stale.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want all those dependencies in your app (your EAR). They are most likely already made available by the container (the application server).
The pom.xml in the ejb-module pulls all those dependencies, so the Maven EAR-plugin does it job as told.

What you need to do is mark all dependencies that is provided by the container as "provided" in the ejb-module's pom.xml.

E.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

Since you are on Wildfly, just import the API:s and remove all those explicit dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Like I said in the comment, use the pom at this page as reference and you will be fine:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/maven-configuration-for-java-ee-7-projects-on-wildfly

Comment: I tried but I receive the same error. I have posted the stack trace into the question.

Comment: Follow the guide here for making an app suitable for deploying on Wildfly: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/maven-configuration-for-java-ee-7-projects-on-wildfly

Comment: I've done the changes to as described into the guide (git was updated).... but the error is still here. I hope the problem isn't in the POM of EJB module "decore"

Comment: The WAR archive has the lib directory, while the JAR archive (EJB)  not... it's normal?

Comment: I have removed all dependencies from the pom and added the API you said... but now I can't build completely ... I miss something... can you check the project on the GIT please?

Comment: I had a glimpse at your code, and I'm having a hard time figuring out what you are trying to accomplish. The container will take are of bootstrapping Hibernate and such, there is normally no need to do that explicitly. You should read up on JPA, there are tons of excellent guides and examples out there.